# How can the Eight Commandments of Source Code Control be modernized?

Tags: version-control

How do you update this? I've never seen any current team that actually "checks out" a file. I don't compile, either. These seem to be from before the days of branching.

1. You shall check in early and check
   in often. You anger your coworkers
   when you check out a file and insist
   on keeping it checked out until some
   future point in time that is
   measured using variables that exist
   solely in your brain.
2. You shall
   never check in code that breaks the
   build. If your code does not compile,
   it does not belong in the source
   control repository.
3. You shall not go
   home for the day with files checked
   out, nor shall you depart for the
   weekend or for a vacation, with
   files checked out.
4. You shall leave a
   descriptive comment when checking in
   your code. You need not include your
   name or the date in the comment as
   that information is already tracked.
5. You shall use the 'Undo Checkout'
   option if you check out a file and
   do not make any changes. It
   displeases your coworkers when you
   check in code that has not changed
   at all from the original.
6. You shall
   not use comments to 'save' defunct
   code.  Fear not, for the code you
   delete still exists in the source
   control code history and can be
   retrieved if needed.
7. You shall use
   source control for more than
   archiving just code. The source code
   control repository makes an
   excellent storage for technical
   docs, SQL scripts, and other
   documents and files related to the
   project.
8. You shall religiously
   backup your source code control
   database on a regular basis and
   store a copy in an off-site
   location.

From http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/posts/13581.aspx

Comment: You think they are outdated? If so, please explain what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Continuous Integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html).

1. Maintain a Single Source Repository
2. Automate the Build
3. Make Your Build Self-Testing
4. Everyone Commits Every Day
5. Every Commit Should Build the Mainline on an Integration Machine
6. Keep the Build Fast
7. Test in a Clone of the Production Environment
8. Make it Easy for Anyone to Get the Latest Executable
9. Everyone can see what's happening
10. Automate Deployment

Answer (score 2):

Whether you do checkouts or not depends on the VCS (Version Control System) you use.  If you use SCCS (old school, but part of the Single Unix Specification), or if you use Atria ClearCase (from IBM Rational), then locking checkouts are a part of life.  With more modern systems, when you create a working sandbox, you effectively do a checkout, but it is a non-locking checkout that does not prevent others from making concurrent changes from the same starting point.

You say you don't compile...I bet your code gets read by some program and then acted on.  Perl doesn't have a separate compiler per se, but it does have a compile phase.  Shell scripts are read and validated.  Likewise Python and Ruby.  The modern form of the rule would perhaps say:

- You shall never checkin code that is not acceptable to its language processor, whether that be an interpreter or a compiler.  If your code is not at least syntactically correct, it does not belong in the main branches of the source control repository (though it might belong in your private working branch).

Item 3, about not leaving code checked out, remains substantially valid.  If you hold code in your sandbox for protracted periods of time, then you are making your own life more difficult as you will probably have more merging to deal with because of others who have worked on the same code while you had it in your private branch.

All the other points seem as valid under Git or SVN or CVS or ... as they are under SCCS or ClearCase.

Answer (score 2):

updates for the year 2008.

1. You shall **commit** early and **commit** often. You anger your coworkers when you **break the build in the main branch**.
2. You shall never check in code **that the build-bot doesn't accept**.
3. You shall not go home for the day **without merging your branch with others'**
4. You shall leave a descriptive comment when checking in your code. You need not include your name or the date in the comment as that information is already tracked.
5. DELETED!
6. You shall not use comments to 'save' defunct code. Fear not, for the code you delete still exists in the source control code history and can be retrieved if needed.
7. You shall use source control for more than archiving just code. The source code control repository makes an excellent storage for technical docs, SQL scripts, and other documents and files related to the project. **You can even use source control on your OpenOffice Documents using the SVN plugin**
8. You shall religiously **mirror your branch on a backup server**.

Answer (score 1):

What is there to "modernize"? I don't see anything that relates to COBOL or Ada...

Answer (score 1):

Why would they **need** to be modernized? They look just as relevant now as they were on the day they were written, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Since most modern source code control systems allow the possibility of concurrent checkouts, I can see where (3) could be relaxed, although it's still a good idea to check in at night so that it gets backed up.  TFS allows you to shelve pending changes so you could save your changes without really checking them in when your code breaks the build but you want to check in before you leave at night.

Answer (score 0):

*You shall not go home for the day with files checked out, nor shall you depart for the weekend or for a vacation, with files checked out.*

*You shall use the 'Undo Checkout' option if you check out a file and do not make any changes. It displeases your coworkers when you check in code that has not changed at all from the original*

*You shall religiously backup your source code control database on a regular basis and store a copy in an off-site location.*

If you have to worry about any of these, your SCM is full of failure. [Get a better one](http://git.or.cz).

The rest of these are pretty good ideas...

Comment: Which SCM system does not require backups - in some shape or form?  If your answer is that DVCS (distributed version control system) does that, then you have to ensure that there are sufficient copies of the code that in fact you don't need to make the backups.